# How to create a pdf from data in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf

I'm building a resume builder. I've made everything else that I'm not able to write the resume data to a pdf and give it to the use.
I have a class user and an object constants that contains data.

```
data class User(
    var id : String? = null,
    var email : String? = null,
    var profileHeadline : String? = "",
    var profileSummary : String? = "",
    var profilePhoto : String? = "",
    var personalInfo: PersonalInfo? = PersonalInfo(),
    var education: MutableList<Education>? = null,
    var experience: MutableList<Experience>? = null,
    var skills : MutableList<Skills>? = null,
    var languages: MutableList<Languages>? = null,
    var interest : MutableList<Interest>? = null,
    var awardAndAchievements: MutableList<AwardAndAchievements>? = null,
    var licenceAndCertification: MutableList<LicenceAndCertification>? = null,
    var projects : MutableList<Projects>? = null,
    var publications: MutableList<Publications>? = null,
    var patents : MutableList<Patents>? = null,
    var volunteerExperience : MutableList<VolunteerExperience>? = null,
    var recommendations: MutableList<Recommendations>? = null
) : Parcelable
```

I want to create a well structured pdf with the data. A well structured pdf means Think about your own resume.
I know some about canvas and pdfdocument in kotlin - Android and also about creating pdfs with activities.

But i don't know which approach should I use and how to make it happen.
Please help!
It will be so nice of you if you can give me an example by creating some resume pdf.

Comment: Which approach to use is opinion based question, the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument have an example of how to use and then you can draw direct to the pdf canvas or you can re-use a view that you have drawn to screen and get it to draw to the pdf canvas.

Comment: @Andrew could you show me how to do it? I've already gone through the documentation and youtube and github also. But it's not helpful.

Comment: @Navneet https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-generate-a-pdf-file-in-android-app/

Comment: @AbdullahJaved I'm using kotlin. It's in java.